# Use Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager inside TypeScript

Tags: asp.net, typescript, webforms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using old ASP.Net WebForms AJAX aka UpdatePanel.
Do have some life, beginning to like Typescript instead of ".js" file.
Now my problem, when I have lines below on my ts file:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(client.pageManagerBeginRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(client.pageManagerPageLoaded);

It complains of error:

**TS2304 TypeScript (TS) Cannot find name 'Sys'**

Comment: in TS you need to pull the library in order to use it. Example
`import Sys from 'library-name'` try looking at APT doc or code for it ?

Comment: First time to use TS. I do not know the library name.

Comment: I think Sys is created on the live page when the ScriptManager 'imports' js files as ScriptResource. I'm not sure you can actually access those. I'd search for 'MicrosoftAjax' js files or similar. You might have to rewrite or keep as normal js. I'm guessing a bit here.